# Sad face with Chrome

Tags: facebook, localhost

I develop Facebook app under VS2010 and localhost. When testing with Chrome I get ablank page with sad face :(
When testing with IE I get a Warning regarding insecure page (that is localhost), after I authorize that warning the page shows correctly.e.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto c:\Windows32\System\drivers\etc\hosts.txt, uncomment the 127.0.0.1 localhost.  Restart Chrome.